# Nginx rewrite rule not working for Wordpress website

Tags: nginx, wordpress

I have wordpress webiste with nginx, Want to rewrite
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine

RewriteBase /sp-services/web-services/

RewriteRule ^v1/(.)/(.)$ $1/$2.php [NC,L] into nginx, but not working

Comment: `RewriteRule` won't work in `nginx` because it is Apache `mod_rewrite` instruction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache mod_rewrite doesn't work at Nginx.

For this case, in nginx you can use something like this:

```
location /sp-services/web-services/v1 {
  rewrite ^/sp-services/web-services/v1/(.)/(.)$ /sp-services/web-services/$1/$2.php break;
}
```